# Abysmal vs Atrocious

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I came across these two words today, having previously known the meaning of atrocious but completely baffled as to the meaning of abysmal. However, Cambridge dictionary database suggests that these two are very synonymous and could be used almost interchangeably.

Abysmal is defined as simply 'very bad' whereas atrocious is defined as 'of very bad quality'.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/atrocious
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abominable

Therefore, would 'his Russian is atrocious' and 'his Russian is abysmal' same thing?

Can anyone shed some light? Much appreciated

Comment: It is difficult to understand nuances of vocabulary through anything but reading. A short cut would be to read through the excerpts that show up on NGram or some other collection of published works. Or look up abyss and atrocity.

Comment: "Abysmal" may carry some connotations of "abyss" -- that is, very, very low -- but it's generally cut free from the metaphor.

Comment: Dictionaries only -hint- at their meaning and usage. You should check many other dictionaries and even then they won't all together capture how they are different. Also, note that you linked to 'abominable', not 'abysmal'. All three are entirely different words. Of course they surely appear in many of the same contexts (all pretty awful). There are no exact synonyms

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed very close/almost interchangeable. I would look at the nouns to which they are usually applied [here](https://wikidiff.com/abysmal/atrocious):

- *atrocious*: crime, act, murder, condition, spelling, grammar.
- *abysmal*: ignorance, record, performance, poverty, conditions, quality, perplexity, result, and failure

... but I would have a hard time giving a more general/abstract difference of when to use which word. I would have to say that "his Russian is atrocious" seems slightly more idiomatic (note that "spelling" and "grammar" are both on the "atrocious" list, but I don't think "his Russian is abysmal" would strike me as unusual.

Comment: I think i'm starting to understand. So, crime(any kind, murder for instance) is atrocious but not abysmal, while working conditions can be both, abysmal and atrocious. Correct? To say that English is vast and complex would be an understatement :)

Comment: @Raskolnikov It is useful to think of the literal origins of the words, _atrocious_ is derived from _atrocity_ while _abysmal_ is derived from _abyss_. This means that _atrocious_ indicates an element of shocked emotional response whereas _abysmal_ refers, metaphorically, to great depth or, in other words, to a very low level. Please note, however, that "his understanding of the topic is abysmal" means the exact opposite of "he understands the topic in great depth", _abysmal_ never has positive connotations.